# Discord ShareX Config Generator

Tags: html, json, discord, webhooks

I am wanting to make a easy to use image upload script for discord alot like [this](https://sevr.org/discord/) but give more variables to use than just the webhook URL and Payload JSON. I am new at coding so really anything helps.

[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/)

Here's an example of what I mean since I am bad with words.

The upload script before user input:

```
{
  "Name": "",
  "DestinationType": "FileUploader",
  "RequestURL": "",
  "FileFormName": "d",
  "Arguments": {
    "payload_json": ""
  },
  "URL": "$json:attachments[0].url$"
}
```

The upload script after user input:

```
{
  "Name": "profile-name-here",
  "DestinationType": "FileUploader",
  "RequestURL": "webhook-here",
  "FileFormName": "d",
  "Arguments": {
    "payload_json": "user-chosen-"
  },
  "URL": "$json:attachments[0].url$"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example payload can be found here: https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/

You can modify the left code and immediately see how it will appear in the channel on the right.

The specification of it can be found here: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

If you have further question you should visit the [ShareX Discord server](https://discordapp.com/invite/sharex). It is a reoccuring question there.

Comment: I forgot to respond to this but I was wanting to do something [like this](https://sevr.org/discord/) just better. Where should I start for getting this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent the past few hours making a NPM Package just for this reason.

I only have one issue with the `DestinationType` but it works as intend.

The example below would make a configuration file with the desired input
that is shown in the example.

```js
'use strict';
const ShareX = require("../index")
ShareX.generateConfig(
    "ShareX-Configs",
    "test",
    "https://test.com/sharex/upload",
    "ImageUploader",
    "POST",
    "test",
    "Text",
    "$json:file.url$"
).then((r) => console.log(r));
```

You can the structure of the package [here](https://github.com/CyberCDN/ShareXGenerator) or [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharexgenerator)